# Assign view to variable programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a class in which I need to get a reference to one of the child views of my UIViewController, for example I need to change the text in every UIViewController from one swift class.

So this is my class:

```
class CustomClass: UIViewController {

   var button: UIView!

   func initClass(controller: UIViewController){
      button = controller.view.getViewByIdentifier("button")
   }

   func changeButtonText(){
      button.text = "changed!"
   }

}
```

with this call I can then initialize it in every UIViewController and change the text with only one method.

But how can I get the reference to the button in each view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate all buttons in view and change their title. Functional swifty way:

```
    self.view.subviews.flatMap { (view) -> UIButton? in
        return view as? UIButton
    }.forEach { (button) -> () in
        button.setTitle("changed!", forState: .Normal)
    }
```

Little explantion: `flatMap` maps the array of subviews returning only `UIButton`s with optionals unwrapped. Then just set title for each of them.

Swift 1.2 (unchecked):

```
    self.view.subviews.map { (view) -> Void in
        if let button = view as? UIButton {
            button.setTitle("changed!", forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: it says: cannot invoke "foreach" with argument list of type (_) -> ()

Comment: Definitely. Swift 2.0 is the future, no sense to write in 1.2 now and then update that code to 2.0. Of course, unless you have a huge project to maintain. I'll post an example for 1.2, but don't have a possibility to check.